# Modify datas in function in angular4 application

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I have an angular 4 application and I want to open a modal dialog with datas from a function.
So, I have a function which has datas :

```
Timeline.prototype.onTaskDoubleClick = function(task){
        console.log("Double click on task " + task.id);
        console.log(task);
        //open dialog
 }
```

In this function I have `task` which contains many datas and I open a modal dialog. In this dialog, I pass datas to projectName and title like this :

```
<app-modal-double-click-on-task  #childModal [projectName]=projectName [title]="title">
```

So, it works when projectName and title are defined before the ngOninit like this :

```
title: string = 'my title';
projectName: string = 'my project';
```

But I want to modified these variables in my first function `Timeline.prototype.onTaskDoubleClick` with the datas from task. So do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Is it angularJS or Angular2/4? If it is angularJS I request you to change tag angular to angularjs.

Comment: It's an Angular 4 application